Live coding Unreal Engine 5
Why is my file in Unreal Engine 5 loading an old recompile from VS studio? Even if I recompile with live coding it continues to keep variables from an earlier VS studio save. I didn't even work on the file yet during this session, just opened my game to play it for a while and noticed several things weren't working yet it was working fine the night before when I last saved my progress
Opened my file frome yesterday and this happened immediately so I closed the programs and restarted my computer hoping this was an error but it did not fix itself. ( I'm learning on Udemy and not super experienced)

From Visual Studio, have you tried to "Rebuild"?

"Opened my file frome yesterday" , what do you mean? Did you reopened the Visual Studio project, or the did you executed the .exe file (the executable that is the result of a compilation at a certain time)?
